# Script with a variable number of Real arguments

Tags: raku

I'm trying to write a Raku script to be called e.g.

`script 1.2 1.117 -2 0.037`

I.e., the idea is to create a `sub MAIN(@numbers)` and somehow get the array `@numbers` as Real (not Str, not IntStr). A way to do so is to cast each element (if possible) in a `for`, but I'm sure there is a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'll let readers judge whether the following is a technically atrocious hack, or looks hideously repugnant, or both. But it's the closest thing I'm aware of in current Raku syntax.

First, you need to accept a variable number of arguments. (You need that for even *your* code to work at all. I presume you typo'd.)

Rather than use `*` or similar I'll use `|`. We'll see why in a mo.

```
sub MAIN( |numbers ) { ... }
```

Next, I add a sub-signature.

```
sub MAIN( |numbers ( *@, :@reals = numbers».Real )) { ... }
```

This takes advantage of:

- Named parameters being optional; **and**
- Establishing a default value based on arguments bound to parameters to the left in a signature; **and**
- Hiding this chicanery so the usage message is not affected, and so that (I *think*) the user cannot inject a value using `--reals=...` or similar. (Actually, saying I think they can't is far too strong. I *hope* they can't.)

This is either a pretty terrible hack or just plain evil. Don't do this at <strike>home</strike> work!

The code so far presumes that the arguments are indeed `Real`s. If they're not, things go wrong. We need to deal with that too.

So we add a `subset` and add that to the signature:

```
subset Reals where *».Real».defined.all;
sub MAIN( Reals |numbers ( *@, :@reals = numbers».Real )) { ... }
```

Here we see the main reason I used `|` rather than `*`; it's the only way to write a type on the left of a slurpy, Without that I'd have to inline the `where` and the whole thing would be even more unspeakably ugly than it is.

Thus we end up with:

```
subset Reals where *».Real».defined.all;
sub MAIN( Reals |numbers ( *@, :@reals = numbers».Real )) { .WHAT.say for @reals }
```

displaying, for your original command line:

```
(Rat)
(Rat)
(Int)
(Rat)
```

Comment: I'm much too ignorant to judge if this is an ugly hack or pure genius, I lean towards the later. Many thanks!

Comment: As you say, beauty is in the eye of the beholder, although it does show off some really interesting signature deconstruction stuff. Personally, I'd still do `sub MAIN(*@input) { my @reals = &coercion … }` and catch the coercion error to provide helpful feedback if necessary, though